# Maven: How to add files to the root inside an EAR with maven-ear-plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven-ear-plugin

I need to add 2 XML files inside an EAR generated with maven-ear-plugin.

Unfortunately, I haven't seen a way to add an arbitrary file to an EAR; the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) of the plugin which reads "The EAR plugin supports the following artifacts: ejb, war, jar, ejb-client, rar, ejb3, par, sar, wsr and har". There's nothing for adding a regular file.

org.apache.maven.plugins
            maven-ear-plugin
            2.3.1
            
                foo
                foo
                1.4
                lib
                
                    
                        ${parent.groupId}
                        foo-web
                        /foo
                    
                    
                      org.richfaces.framework
                      richfaces-api
                    
                    
                      commons-lang
                      commons-lang

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [maven-ear-plugin 2.4.2](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html) you can use config elements earSourceDirectory, earSourceExcludes and earSourceIncludes to declare extra files to include in the EAR.

By default you simply place those files to ${basedir}/src/main/application folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I had the ejb.properties file under ejbs/src/main/resources and had used earSourceDirectory and earSourceIncludes to pull the file from the ejbs directory to the ear.  However, it did not *reliably* put it in the lib directory.  The EJB does not find it in .; it looks for it in the lib directory.

To fix this, I created the src/main/application/lib directory and created a link to the ejb.properties file.  I then removed the earSourceDirectory and Includes properties.  Now when I do a mvn clean package, it automatically pulls the properties file and puts it in the lib directory of the ear.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be late for @wishihadabettername but I had same issue recently, more I couldn't move the files to include because they were in other folder then earSourceDirectory. I read [maven-ear-plugin ear:ear documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html) and thought about how to move my `release` folder on the root of ear.

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: package.

and

> **workDirectory** - Directory that resources are copied to during the build.
>
> **Default value is:** *${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}*.

Then my submodule pom.xml looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase> <!-- before package phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Work Directory of Ear plugin -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory> 
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- my resource folder -->
                        <directory>release</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope it help people from now on