# Maven: how to copy & filter *test* resources in an EAR module?

Tags: filtering, maven, ear

I'm trying to get Maven to filter & copy two files used for testing.

I've tried putting them in src/test/resources as well as src/test/application (in case it works [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944959/maven-how-to-add-files-to-the-root-inside-an-ear-with-maven-ear-plugin) to src/main/application) but nothing happens.

The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/filtering-sources.html) doesn't say anything about test resources.

Thanks in advance!

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals><goal>read-project-properties</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${filter.build.props}</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <displayName>myapp</displayName>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib</defaultJavaBundleDir>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
<filters>
    <filter>${filter.build.props}</filter>
</filters>
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Test resources aren't packaged in the final package (be it JAR, WAR, EAR). I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly but maybe you're actually looking for a solution based on filtering and profiles (to pick up the wanted filter).